# Camera calibration and point projection from 3D to 2D image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am trying to project a 3D point from a pointcloud to a 2D panorama image. I have manually picked 8 points on the 2D image and the corresponding 3D pointcloud points and used the OpenCV library to find the camera matrix, translation, and rotation vectors that are then used in projection method.

```
#initial camera matrix
camera_matrix = cv2.initCameraMatrix2D([objectPoints_3D],[imagePoints_2D], image_size_2D)

#calibrate cameras
intrinsics_error, intrinsic_matrix, intrinsics_distortion_coeffs, rotation_vectors, translation_vectors = cv2.calibrateCamera([objectPoints_3D], [imagePoints_2D], image_size_2D, camera_matrix, None, flags=cv2.CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS) #camera_matrix and intrinsic_matrix are the same

#project a 3D point in the pointcloud onto a 2D image
projected_point_2D = cv2.projectPoints(selected_point_3D, rotation_vectors[0], translation_vectors[0], intrinsic_matrix, intrinsics_distortion_coeffs)
```

The `projected_point_2D` seems reasonable for the same image that I used when calibrating, but fails in another set of 2D and 3D images. Am I doing this wrong?

Images contain buildings and trees

Comment: [cv2.projectPoints](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv2.projectPoints) does the opposite: given a 3D point in some coordinate frame (and camera intrinsic calibration, and camera rotation/translation relative to the coordinate frame), it returns a 2D point in the image plane.

It looks like you want to obtain a 3D point location given a 2D point in the image + camera calibration. But that information is only sufficient to obtain a ray; to obtain a point, you also need to know the depth.

Comment: @vasiliykarasev my bad, going to make changes, thank you for spotting this

Comment: you need more calibration points. Not sure whether this worka at all for a panorama, because that image probably doesnt follow the pinhole camera model at all

Comment: @Micka but why do I then get reasonable results for the same 2D-3D pair of pictures that I used during the calibration?

Comment: because your calibration was optimized for those pairs. By the way, I'm not completely sure what you did during calibration, can you show some sample panorama images that you used for calibration? Do you have a live-system with a fixed stitching, or some one-time panorama stitching (e.g. from keypoints)?

Comment: @Micka 2D panorama image https://drive.google.com/file/d/19vI5O-TEf0q8KBr1uH7pVXnzdUUIgiuH  and the corresponding 3D image https://drive.google.com/file/d/19tv9Z2tB81buWTJdhtK1ftA34xjLUoZw with the total of 33 points used for calibration. I have also used `CV_CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL` flag to get more deformation coefficients. I understand that I could have just optimised calibration for one image only. But shouldn't the resulting transformation matrix be the same for any 2D-3D pair since sensors spatial relationships stay the same? I do not know myself what algorithm was used for stitching..

Comment: I dont think this panorama setup is compatible to a calibration camera model, but I'm no expert in complex calibration problems, so I might be wrong. With your computed distortion coefficients, can you undistort the image to see whether the calibration makes any sense?

Comment: with your stitched images setup, can you create more recordings, like holding a chessboard pattern in a few hundred of images all over the panorama positions?

Comment: @Micka I have been thinking how I could apply distortion coefficients to an image to see the result. Is there a way to do that with the opencv? There are papers out there that do calibration between "velodyne" and "ladybug" sensors (these are the ones that are being used). I should probably just read them. I am trying to avoid doing calibration with the chessboard because I do not want to record this data and do the preparations.. :) How many points in your experience is enough to perform proper calibation and is chessboard actually needed?

Comment: I dont have any experience with such post-stitching calibration, but looks like a nice topic. You can use opencv's cv2.undistort function (or initUndistortRectifyMap and remap functions if you need it more efficiently for multiple images).